# What is the physical size and population details of Ankh-Morpork?

Tags: discworld

For a project, I am currently working on, I have been trying to find out the size of Ankh-Morpork.
How many houses/dwellings are there, what's the population and the physical size of the city?

There is [some information](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Ankh-Morpork) on Discworld & Terry Pratchett Wiki but I am not sure how accurate that is, due to it mentioning a population of about 1 million and the city being a mile across. The population would make sense, but surely the city is larger than a mile across?

This information may be in the *[The Compleat Ankh-Morpork](https://www.discworldemporium.com/companions-maps/30-the-compleat-ankh-morpork)* but I don't own this currently.

Comment: i don't know whether one mile across is too small, considering that there are dwarves in the city which mainly live underground...

Comment: There's also [The Streets of Ankh-Morpork](http://www.amazon.com/Streets-Ankh-Morpork-Stephen-Briggs/dp/0552141615) which might help. Also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ankh-Morpork) claims "about five miles (8 km) across" although doesn't say where that comes from.

Comment: (Darn comment edit time limit) And to @Armin's point, the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ankh-Morpork) article says there are "50,000 dwarfs living there" and references *The Truth* and *The Fifth Elephant* for that.

Comment: @blm nice to know, I thought that there would be more dwarves given that they are almost always mentioned xD

Comment: The one mile figure may well be accurate in a strict institutional sense, while not reflecting what anyone living there thinks of as "the city". For instance, see the limits of the "City of London", a district within what we all think of as London: https://goo.gl/maps/GnbBneSs1tB2

Comment: @recognizer Well the "City of London" has a population of ~7.5k but ~300k work/go there (according to wikipedia).  So I am starting to think the 1 million is for the surrounding areas outside of the walls as well not the central part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Population:

Approx. 100,000 souls and ten times more inhabitants.

> "Ankh-Morpork! Brawling city of a hundred thousand souls! And, as the Patrician privately observed, ten times that number of actual people." - **Guard!, Guards!** (thanks to Valorum)
>
> Poets have tried to describe Ankh-Morpork and they have failed. Perhaps it's the sheer zestful vitality of the place, or maybe it's just that a city with a million inhabitants and no sewers is rather robust for poets,... - **Mort** *(Mort's first visit on his way to get a curry after being hired)*

But also importantly

> “What sort of place is Ankh?” “A city of a million souls,” said the voice of Om, “many of them occupying bodies" - **Small Gods**

What's so important about the last one? It's 100 years earlier, meaning that either Ankh-Morpork has no population growth or that all such values must be taken with a significant pinch of salt.

---

## Size:

**Size from Lspace**    1 mile across (about 1.6km) (excluding suburbs outside the city walls) : *I disagree with this*
**Size from Wikipedia** 5 miles across (8km) : *I disagree with this too*.

However I can find no direct references to the size of the city and [the map](http://www.abload.de/img/255118afjku.jpg) has no scale. (Yay I found my map! It was with the maps rather than on the triple stacked Pratchett shelf)

> 'Er...bingle bingle bingle...?' said a small and very nervous voice.
> Vimes pulled out the Gooseberry and stared at it. At a time like this...
> 'Well?' he said.
> 'It's twenty-nine minutes past five, Insert Name Here,' said the imp nervously.
> 'So?'
> 'On foot, at this time of day, you will need to leave now to be home at six o'clock,' said the imp. - **Thud**

Now in the above quote, before getting home just in time for 6pm, Vimes is at 3 Tenth Egg Street and needs to get to 1 Scoone Avenue. From the map, that's just over half way across the city, but there's no direct route. I'm estimating that a brisk walk from the Commander of the Watch is 4mph, 30mins would be 2 miles. Tracing the route on the ground against the direct route as the crow flies I estimate the size of the city to be **approximately 3miles diameter** within the walls.

In historical terms this is *very large* for a walled city. 1 mile would be far more reasonable.

---

This leads to population density.

Significant.

In Thud we're introduced to Grag Bashfull Bashfullsson who lives in a corner of a room sublet from an entire family living in the same room. There are other examples of characters living in cramped lodgings consisting of a single room in a boarding house (Carrot, Angua, John Keel, Glod, etc). It should be considered relatively normal for people to be living entire families in single rooms to make up that population in such limited space.

---

## The city

[image: Map of Ankh-Morpork]

Comment: The problem with quoting from a fan-written wiki article is that it's fan-written.

Comment: @Valorum is that not considered acceptable here? I find the wiki is pretty accurate

Comment: It's not a question of acceptability, but one of reliability. A wiki is a secondary source of info. We prefer primary sources of info

Comment: @Valorum, I've got one primary source, just trying to track down the other on the great shelf of primary source ;)

Comment: [This](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/primary-sources-vs-wikis) might help. I see the answer improving with every edit...

Comment: "*Ankh-Morpork! Brawling city of a hundred thousand souls! And, as the Patrician privately observed, ten times that number of actual people.*" - Guard!, Guards!

Comment: "*“What sort of place is Ankh?”
“A city of a million souls,” said the voice of Om, “many of them occupying bodies*" - Small Gods

Comment: *"*What more need be said? A sprawling place, home to a million people, greatest of cities on the Discworld, located on either side of the river Ankh, a waterway so muddy that it looks as if it is flowing upside down.*" - Men At Arms

Comment: "*There were a million people in the city*" - Night Watch.

Comment: @Valorum, note a total lack of mentions of geographical size, I've found one suitable reference that I'm writing up

Comment: Problematically, the number of citizens doesn't seem to rise in line with the growth of the city. I suspect that the actual number may be dramatically higher or lower. The myth is that the city has a million people, just like the myth that there are a billion Chinese people.

Comment: A scan/photo of the aforementioned map would be a nice addition

Comment: @Valorum, I've added a link to one someone has uploaded, it's a big image and I don't actually know how to control image size here.

Comment: Some items for scale; *“Good grief [said Carrot after discovering a dead body at the Guild of Beggars]” “What is it?” “It must have come from the roof of the operahouse.” “Yes? So?” “That’s more than two hundred yards away.”* - http://i.stack.imgur.com/4BitE.png

Comment: @Valorum, I suspect if you scale that up as 200yards you'll get a city about a mile across. It's hard to estimate on such a short distance but it looks about 1/8.

Comment: "*The Ankh-Morpork palace grounds were considered the high spot, if such it could be called, of his career. For example, they contained the ornamental trout lake, **one hundred and fifty yards long**"* - Men at Arms; http://i.stack.imgur.com/zLtel.png

Comment: @Valorum, that lake doesn't fit in the grounds as drawn on the map if it's 200 yards from Opera House to Beggars Guild, we'd have to assume Carrot grossly underestimated the range.

Comment: @Valorum - The "myth" that there are a billion Chinese people? China's population is over 1.3 billion. Even if by some extraordinary error that figure  had a error of +/- 20%, China would still have a billion people.

Comment: @jonah - It has long been a matter of state pride that China has a billion people, so much so that various official censuses have been cancelled because they don't reflect that. The last official country-wide population census was in the late 1980s and even then, the figures were likely tampered with in order to get them over the magic number. The figure of 1.28Bn is simply that 1989 number x 4% growth and totally disregarding any pesky famines that the government chooses not to tell the world about. What's the **actual** number? The Chinese govt probably know, but they ain't telling.

Comment: @Valorum - I mean, the last official census was in 2010 at the latest, so I don't think the number is "just" extrapolated from the 80s numbers.

Comment: @Jonah - I'm no expert, but my understanding is that the 2010 census had been widely discredited with up to 90% of census staff admitting (confidentially) to simply inventing the numbers they submitted. I'll ask over on Skeptics:SE if you'd like :-)

Comment: @Valorum - Sure, please do that. They are the experts on this sort of thing.

Comment: @Separatrix could do with a summary on this answer to my questions.  I also think the measurements in the other links in comments could help prove the actual / approx size (I accept there is no cannon this).  This is a really good answer btw :)

Comment: @Dreamwalker, the final part of your question, about the number of dwellings; I don't think that could be reasonably guessed at by anyone other than maybe a historical sociologist. There are also other problems with the size and population by Pterry was always deliberately vague, as explained by the blurb in the front of the map. e.g. The city doubled in size from Night Watch to say Feet of Clay (?30yrs), but the population remained 1 million from Small Gods to Feet of Clay (>100yrs).

Comment: Even at 3 miles diameter, that's 141,000/mi—that'd be the most dense city in the world, and even very high up for a part of a city. E.g., twice as dense as Manhattan. I blame the intense magical field.

Comment: @derobert, yes, he makes reference to entire families living in one room and still letting space in the room to someone else. Remember also that most of those people are on one side of the river "proud Ankh, Turnwise of the river, and pestilent Morpork on the Widdershins side"

Answer (score 0):

> ‘’s woman?’ said Colon. He screwed up his sweating face with the
>   effort of thought. ‘’s eight miles wide, sir. ‘’s gotta river in it.
>   Lots of, of houses and stuff, sir,’ he reasoned.

According to the map from "The Compleat Ankh-Morpork" that has a scale, the size of the city horizontally is about 2 km (5900 ft). But the size of a foot is not known to us, nor is the size of their mile.